# How can I solve like this exercise

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Let we have the following initial value problem : 
$$y'=f(x,y)=e^y$$
With the condition $y(0)=0$

Find the largest interval $|x| \le a $ makes the initial value problem has an unique solution

Someone told me that : I can find the value of constant $a$ by using the  mean value theorem

Comment: Have you heard about separation of variables techniques?

Comment: I don't want to solve the differential equation , I want to find the value of constant $a$

Comment: Solve it first and then you will see what $a$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$e^{-y(s)}y'(s)=1,$$
hence
$$\left(e^{ -y(s )}\right)'=-1.$$
Integrate with respect to $s$ from $0$ to $x$:
$$e^{-y(x)}-e^{-y(0)}=0-x,$$so
$$y(x) =-\ln(1-x).$$
This should be sufficient to find the parameter $a$.